# Quartz Composer: How do I change the appearance of patch connection cords?

Tags: user-interface, quartz-composer

I accidentally did something and converted my connection cords/noodles/cables from bezier curves to straight lines.

Is there a way to get them back? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some time around the release of 4.x, node connections in Quartz Composer switched from bezier to straight lines. It is possible to revert back to bezier node connections by installing the following open source Quartz Composer plugin by Bartosz Ciechanowski.

https://github.com/Ciechan/QCCableConnections